# why is my static pointer not accessible

Tags: c++, qt, static

I am making a C++ application in Qt and want to load a login keyboard (QWidget) whenever I call the constructor of the corresponding ui-class. The constructor is called everytime I switch to my login window. When I leave this window, the destructor is called and everything is destroyed, so i don't leave a single bit in my RAM. i want also just to have one instance the keyboard (singleton) and then hide() and show() whenever needed.

When I call the constructor the first time, i create an instance of my keyboard and add it to my verticalLayout. This works fine. But when i call the constructor for a second time, e.g. when I switch to another window and switch back to my login window, then my static keyboard becomes unreachable. This is what my debugger says...it's unreachable. So i already have an instance of my keyboard and i just want to add it to my verticalLayout again and I don't get it why i can't access it. Maybe it is some property of static variables, i really don't as I am new to C++. So here is my code

```
#ifndef LOGINKEYBOARD_H
#define LOGINKEYBOARD_H

#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui
{
    class LoginKeyboard;
}

class LoginKeyboard : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit LoginKeyboard(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~LoginKeyboard();

    static LoginKeyboard * instance()
    {
     if (!loginKeyboard)
     {
        loginKeyboard = new LoginKeyboard();
     }

     return loginKeyboard;
    }

private:
    Ui::LoginKeyboard *ui;
    static LoginKeyboard * loginKeyboard;

private slots:



};

#endif // LOGINKEYBOARD_H

#include "headerFiles/loginkeyboard.h"
#include "ui_loginkeyboard.h"

LoginKeyboard *LoginKeyboard::loginKeyboard = 0;

LoginKeyboard::LoginKeyboard(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::LoginKeyboard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

LoginKeyboard::~LoginKeyboard()
{
    delete ui;
}


#include "headerFiles/support.h"
#include "ui_support.h"
#include "headerFiles/mainwindow.h"
#include "headerFiles/loginkeyboard.h"

Support::Support(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Support)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);     
    MainWindow::setPreviousPage(MainWindow::widgetStack->first());
    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(LoginKeyboard::instance()); //error when it gets called the 2nd time
}

Support::~Support()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: Is `ui->verticalLayout->addWidget` expecting an allocated pointer, so that when `ui` is destroyed it'll delete the widget that was added (your instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your static instance of `LoggingKeyboard` it will be deleted by it when the layout is destroyed.

See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#addItem)

> Note: The ownership of item is transferred to the layout, and it's the layout's responsibility to delete it.

So it's not a good idea to have a singleton subclass of QWidget. If you *really* need the singleton property - you could extract the necessary functionality to a different class (which will not be subclassing `QWidget`) and use it from `LoginKeyboard`. However, if you don't *really* need it - then just don't do it - singletons should be avoided as much as possible because they are just glorified versions of global variables and may cause a wide variety of hard-to-track bugs.